# Visual editor for math expressions, with basic or better yet, full Unicode support

Tags: windows, gratis, math, portable, unicode

I am looking for a separate, standalone **visual** math editor. Requirements:

1. Full or, at least, basic Unicode support (explanation below).
2. Portable by nature. It means that all the app needs for functioning is its own directory, without a need to install additional dependencies at the OS level. It also means that .NET/Java apps are not an option.
3. Open-source or, at least, free.

Two best known apps — [MathType](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/) and
[MathMagic](http://www.mathmagic.com/) — have no support for Unicode! That is, you cannot copy any char to clipboard and then paste it into your formula. You will get question marks instead of unrecognized characters. This is because these two applications rely only on their own internal tables, which store some information on chars that are considered to deserve registration, and ignore other (“unregistered”) chars. This approach is absolutely inappropriate for me. Moreover, these products have many serious disadvantages of closed commercial apps. They use undocumented formats and features, they have no portable versions, etc. And MathType has not been developed for a very long time (the current version, 6.9, was released a long time ago).

[EquaThEque ® Visual Math Editor](http://visualmatheditor.equatheque.net/site/documentation.html) is not even a **visual** editor, it’s a browser-based code editor with some kind of GUI for MathJax (Javascript!). It is definitely not what I want to use (the same applies to such things as e.g. [mathquill](http://mathquill.com/) or [codecogs.com/eqneditor](http://www.codecogs.com/eqneditor)).

[Hermitech Laboratory Formulator 4.0 MathML Weaver](http://www.mmlsoft.com/index.php/downloads) is free (for non-commercial purposes) and even has a portable version, but... it seriously lacks many important features (in comparison with MathType/MathMagic), thus being too inconvenient to use. Moreover, it does not **fully** support Unicode, because I cannot use such things as e.g. [U+1D465 — MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL X](https://codepoints.net/U+1D465), but at least it supports Unicode at a basic level. But this project does not seem to be actively developed — the current version was released in the year 2009!

Regarding TeX-based systems (such as [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/)), or Word/LibreOffice etc. — their functionality for WYSIWYG-styled editing of math expressions looks too poor to me, compared to professional-level, separate editors (such as MathType/MathMagic).

Actually, I am afraid that there is no app to answer my question, but maybe there exists some modern, new and fresh project that I am not aware of?